# ネットワークの安定性を計測する方法

Tags: network

現在の作業環境でルーターが遠かったせいか速度が出る時は十分に出るのですが、一日に1,2回`ping`の半分ぐらいがパケットロスになってしまうほど安定しなくなる時があったので中継機を買いました。

実際に安定化したか確認するためにとりあえずpingをgoogle.co.jpに向けて立ち上げて確認してるのですが、もっとネットワークの状態を長時間監視するための適切なコマンドやツールはありますか？

できればMac上で使えるものを探しています。

Comment: なにをもって「ネットワークの安定性」と判断するかの定義が無いと話が迷走するでしょう。例えば同一 HUB に接続した２台が通信できないとしたら、安定性以前の問題で単なる故障っス（どれが故障しているかはまた話が別）この手の測定ツールが負荷をかけることで、せっかく安定しているネットワークが過負荷になるなんてこともよくあるっス。とりあえず社外サイト (google) に無益な負荷をかけるのは良くないですよ。

Comment: そうですね、ネットワークの安定性の定義にどのようなものがあるか調べてもわからなかったので質問をしたのですが、定義を正確に述べられるほど詳しくなってから再度調べることにします。

Comment: ネットワークの話は接続元（自分の PC）と接続先（インターネットの彼方）の両方、更には経路の話が絡んでくるので、「安定」って定義が難しいんですよね。更には `ping` なんかだとセキュリティソフトが禁じてたりするので、ネットワーク以外の話が絡んできたりします。だから一般論は無くて定義次第ってことで。